# How to integrate $\cos2\pi\left(x+\frac{n}{x}\right)$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

This is a follow up question of [Integrate $\cos^2(\pi x)\cos^2(\frac{n\pi}{x})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1791324/integrate-cos2-pi-x-cos2-fracn-pix). By using product to sum formula, this could be converted to question to integrate $$\int\cos2\pi\left(x+\frac{n}{x}\right)\text{d}x, \text{ where } 2 \le x \le n$$
But this seems hard to integrate too. Very appreciate if you can help to make any progress.

Comment: If this is the same integral as in your other question, you should edit that question, not post another one. Or it will just be closed